# != operator in Java for loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

How come the below code prints "The value of J is: 1000"?
I would've thought that the "j != 1000" would evaluate to false in all instances (Because 1000 mod 19 is not 0), hence making it an infinite loop.

```
public static void loop2() {
    int j = 0;

    for(int i=0;j != 1000;i++) {
        j = j+19;
    }
    System.out.println("The value of J is: " + j);
}
```

Comment: I'd imagine that at some point you will overflow int - and then the value you get could become 1000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you defined your j as int.
Integers have a defined range. The Max-Value of the signed Integer is 2,147,483,647. As soon as you go over that value you have a bit-overflow which causes the whole thing to start at the min value. In case of Integers thats -2,147,483,648. At some point in the loop you get to a negativ starting value of the loop which leads your loop to land at 981+19 = 1000 >>> loop is exited, cause J equals your exit-condition of your for-loop.

Answer (score 14):

Max value of int in java is `2,147,483,647` on adding 19 to j, again and again, this value will be passed. After which it will start again from min value of int i.e. `-2,147,483,648`.

This will continue until the value of j become 1000 at some point. Hence, the loop will stop.

`j` will iterate 17 times over the max value of the integer to reach this point. Code for checking:

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int j = 0;
        int iterationCount = 0;

        for(int i=0;j != 1000;i++) {
            j = j+19;
            if(j - 19 > 0 && j < 0) {
                iterationCount ++;
            }

        }
        System.out.println("The value of J is: " + j + " iterationCount: " + iterationCount);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
The value of J is: 1000 iterationCount: 17
```

Comment: As side note, it will overflow and loop back again ~17 times before it reaches 1000.

Answer (score 4):

Scanning for overflows like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int j = 0;
  for(int i=0;j != 1000;i++) {
    j = j+19;
    if(j < Integer.MIN_VALUE+19){
      System.out.println("overflow");
    }
  }
  System.out.println("The value of J is: " + j);
}
```

prints

```
overflow
overflow
overflow
overflow
overflow
overflow
overflow
overflow
overflow
overflow
overflow
overflow
overflow
overflow
overflow
overflow
overflow
The value of J is: 1000
```

meaning the j overflows 17 times until the increment by 19 finally hits 1000.

Answer (score 1):

This is, as Saheb stated, due to the integer overflow.

The value of J, 1000, is reached after 3842865528 iterations

```
public static void loop2()
{
    int j = 0;
    long iterations = 0;

    for (int i = 0; j != 1000; i++) {
        j = j + 19;
        iterations++;
    }
    System.out.println("The value of J is: " + j + " reached after " + iterations + " iterations");
}
```